# Animate textarea when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I’m relatively new to javascript and am really struggling with an issue. I have a textarea in a popup (using JQM) that updates the text when a button is clicked. The text it updates with is randomly selected from an array. 
What I am trying to do is add some animation to the textarea or the text itself when it is updated, as sometimes the randomly selected text is the same as what is in there and it looks as though nothing has happened…
I hope that makes sense. The javascript code I have (and works apart from animation) is: 
Hope someone can help me…
Thanks

function playName() {

```
var player = [];
var x = document.getElementById("playerName");

player.push(document.getElementById("player1").value);
player.push(document.getElementById("player2").value);

var i = document.forms["playerForm"]["player1"].value;
var ii = document.forms["playerForm"]["player2"].value;
    if (i == null || i == "") {
    alert("Please enter a name for player 1");
    return false;

    } else {

        if(ii == null || ii == ""){
        alert("Please enter a name for player 2");
        return false;

        } else {

            var randomName = player[Math.floor(Math.random()*player.length)]            
            document.getElementById("playerName").innerHTML = randomName;

        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `click` event and `animate` to do this, like for example :

```
$("#yourButton").click(function(){
    $("textarea").fadeOut().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

See more information about this on the jQuery API documentation : 
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You can also [check this JSFiddle for an example](https://jsfiddle.net/La6t7jg7/4/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll look in to using that some more. Had a quick play and managed to change size and opacity. What I would like to do is fade out and fade in again after 2 seconds. Is that possible?